# SPHINX output compression?

Tags: compression, sphinx, resultset

Is there any option available to get the SPHINX result set in a compressed format? like gzip etc.,

Answer (score 0):

No not directly. Possible ideas

1. Install a lightweight proxy on the same server as sphinx. That takes to sphinx in the background, but compresses the data back to the real client. (possibly using json or similar, that should compress well - do this rather than trying to compress sphinxes binary protocol - because would have to decode it with the sphinx api code)
2. Use a SSH tunnel - and enable compression on the tunnel. But SSH might negate the small benefit you might see with the compression.
3. Use SphinxQL. There is a compression setting for the mysql client - but I dont know for sure that sphinx supports it server side.

Comment: 1. Install a lightweight proxy on the same server as sphinx. - Can you please suggest a lightweight proxy and a brief input about configuring it with SHPINX?

Comment: One I use: http://www.nearby.org.uk/geograph/sample1.phps Installed on a Apache webserver with PHP support. Because it HTTP based, was also easy to install varnish in front of it for caching purposes.